# tikzDevice in R on mac OS X el Capitan

Tags: r, macos

I do not manage to make R/tikzDevice works correctly since I have made the Mac OS X el Capitan update two days ago...

The problem is that R/tikzDevice seems no longer to be able to write anything on any plot: I have the curves, the points, the axes, etc., but no text at all (no graduation, no legend, etc.).

Here is a dummy "not-working example":

```
library('tikzDevice')
tikz('DUMMYtest.tex', standAlone = TRUE, width=4, height=4)
plot(c(),pch=3,col='grey',xlim=c(-1,1),ylim=c(-1,1),xlab='',ylab='',axes=T)
points(0,0,pch=3,cex=1,col='red')
points(0,-0.5,pch=19,cex=1,col='blue')
text(0,0.5,'blablabla')
dev.off()
```

Does anybody manage to make R/tikzDevive works on el Capitan?
I have installed macTeX-2015 and LaTeX works fine.

Comment: Re-install MacTex. That's the path of least resistance to these types of issues.

Comment: Thank you. Just done... And it does not work. I have moved to MacTeX-2015 (you d'on't have the choice with "el Craptain" ;-) ), and my LaTeX stuffs work properly.

Comment: Your example works on my el Capitan system using the latest CRAN version, tikzDevice_0.9  with MacTEX-2015.

Comment: If I just apply my example, when I call 'library(tikzDevice)', I have a message like 'tikzDevice: No appropriate LaTeX compiler could be found...'

Comment: Just try on the mac of a friend: exactly the same problem; R creates a .tex file that you can compile, but the .pdf (and the tikzpicture) then does not contain any text. @user25494: have you text in your .pdf file ?

Comment: Yes, I've pasted the .tex, .log and .pdf files at: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/zb52ie94a3znltw/AACF04GREXX714rXDjoYLPlDa?dl=0

Answer (score 0):

I have solved my problem by making a full installation of R, Latex and Co via Homebrew, following exactly this link (the boot-strap step of "instal r" takes a relatively long time, don't be afraid ;-) ):

http://www.r-bloggers.com/installing-r-on-os-x-100-homebrew-edition/

Thanks.